# How to fix the position of a UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

I have a `UIPopoverController` and a `UITextfield` embedded in it. When I tap the text field, the keyboard pops up and my popover controller shift up a bit to make space for the keyboard. But I want my popover to stay in the same position no matter if the keyboard is present. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the text field in a scroll view? If so, that's automatic behavior.

Comment: @matt No, its position is fixed inside the popover controller.

Comment: Well, I still don't think there is anything you can do. It is automatic behavior. Why would you not want the text field to make room for the keyboard?

Comment: @matt Well, I'm doing something a bit tricky. If the popover view change its position, the look of some other view will be messed up. Seems I'll have to find some workaround for this.

Comment: This sounds like a misuse of a popover. You are not in charge of where a popover appears; if you want to be in charge a view's position, don't use a popover. In iOS 7 you can float a presented view over the rest of the interface; that might be a better solution.

Comment: @matt I tried your suggestion and it works perfectly for me. It even gives me more options of animation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple popover controller adjusts itself to appear above the keyboard, and you cannot change this behavior. You only options is to either roll your own implementation or use an open-source popover implementation.